# How to use SYSTEM headers with CMake and clang-tidy?

Tags: c++, cmake, clang-tidy

I am trying to use `clang-tidy` in my CMake (3.17.1) project however it crashes on the `Catch2` test library header. Setting the Catch2 as a system header does not seem to help. The command invoked for clang-tidy contains the path to `Catch2` as a system include directory yet the diagnostics is still printed for it. When trying to isolate it I have discovered that this does not actually work with clang-tidy:

`clang-tidy src.cpp -- -Isystem/Path/to/header`

It results in the header not being found at all. What I have learned somewhere (cannot find it now) was to make it actually two `--extra-arg` parameters of the clang-tidy instead:

`clang-tidy --extra-arg=-Isystem --extra-arg=/Path/to/header src.cpp`

This however does not work everywhere. On Windows I was able to make it work but on Linux it never worked in any form (together, separate, after `--`). How does one use the `-isystem` headers with `clang-tidy` on Linux? It is very confusing and inconsistent. Furthermore how to do it with CMake?

I have this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY clang-tidy)

add_library(Catch2 STATIC Catch2/Catch2.cpp Catch2/include/Catch2/catch.hpp)
target_include_directories(Catch2 SYSTEM PUBLIC Catch2/include)

add_executable(SomeTest SomeTest/test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Catch2)
```

The generated command line is rather convoluted (wrapping is mine for readability):

```
cmake 
-E __run_co_compile 
--tidy="clang-tidy-10;--extra-arg-before=--driver-mode=g++"
--source=../Sometest/test.cpp
-- 
/usr/bin/clang++-10
-isystem ../Catch2/include 
-g
-std=gnu++17
-MD
-MT CMakeFiles/SomeTest.dir/projects/SomeTest/test.cpp.o 
-MF CMakeFiles/SomeTest.dir/projects/SomeTest/FileTest.cpp.o.d 
-o CMakeFiles/SomeTest.dir/projects/SomeTest/test.cpp.o 
-c 
../projects/SomeTest/test.cpp
```

In the output there are warnings from the Catch2 so the `system` in the include is just ignored seemingly. I have tried to force the `--extra-arg` via the `CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY` property:

`set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY clang-tidy --extra-arg=-isystem --extra-arg=../Catch2/include)`

but that does not seem to do the trick either.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have better luck if you tell `clang-tidy` to use a compilation database?  CMake can generate those automatically for you, and `clang-tidy` will leverage the exact same flags you'd use to build.

Comment: @StephenNewell I have enabled the compilation database in CMake and used it with clang-tidy manually (e.g. `clang-tidy ../SomeTest/test.cpp`) from the directory where the compilation commands json is. It was picked up fine and it does include the same `-isystem` header. Interestingly it does find the header fine this time but still ignores the `system` as it prints the warnings for the header regardless.

Comment: @StephenNewell As it turns out the problem is not universal but seem specific to Catch2 header (and possibly similar uses of macros). The `-isystem` mostly works when I try to simulate it and even for Catch2 for the most part. However some warnings still bleed through it no matter what (unfortunately from `REQUIRE` macro). I have submitted a bug to LLVM: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45528

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am following [your repro](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45528) as posted on LLVM bugtracker.

You are doing everything correctly: that is, marking Catch2 as system include with `SYSTEM`. `clang-tidy` is also behaving correctly: it only checks your source file `test.cpp` and doesn't fully check `catch.hpp`, only the macro expansion.

The problem is the outdated version of Catch2. `hicpp-vararg` warning has been [silenced](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/commit/f0e596e2522f64451f6444edab5c59b8b9e8e082) as of Catch2 2.12.2, so you need to update to at least that version. Moreover, apparently the core issue that `hicpp-vararg` reported upon has been [fixed](https://reviews.llvm.org/rGe21c3f223a3537df0d9d02fce5038b3d7b98ab52) and this change is expected to be present in clang-tidy 11 release.